# UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities Internet Connection

Tags: ios, xcode

My iOS app needs Internet connection to do what it's designed to do. I don't really care how the connection is provided, meaning through WiFi or Cell service.

What do I need to include in my `Info.plist` file?

I see `telephony` and `wifi` as options that seem related to connection. Do I need both?

I understand I can require more and tone it down later. Apple states if more capabilities added later, existing users may not be able to use the app. Another feature that I will later need is GPS but not in this version. What's the right approach to that? Do I require GPS now or later?

Comment: Further to Matt's answer, `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` is the set of device capabilities required to *install* your app.  It doesn't control anything at runtime.  Since all devices have a networking capability, any device can install your app.  You need to handle no network connectivity at runtime,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No iOS device lacks networking hardware of some sort, so there is no need to limit what devices can download this app. So don't require anything. Just fail gracefully if there happens to be no Internet connection (Apple will check for this).